# QR factorization of complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have two complex numbers $a,b$ how can you find the QR factorization of

$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
       aI_n\\
         bI_n \end{bmatrix} $,

I can't seem to be able to do it. I tried an earlier trick, but I now know it's not necessary true for complex numbers. Is there anyway to do this?

I think if I use a Givens algorithm I should be able to reduce it to a QR factorization.

Answer (score 6):

This may be done with the same complex Givens rotations on the pairs of rows. Here is the math, with $c$ and $s$ complex:
$$\pmatrix{c & s \\ -\bar{s} & \bar{c}} \begin{bmatrix}
       a\\
         b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ca + sb \\ -\bar{s}a + \bar{c}b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} * \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
The element (*) will have magnitude of $\sqrt{|a|^2 + |b|^2}$.
To ensure the matrix is unitary, we only need $|c|^2 + |s|^2 = 1$.

For $$-\bar{s}a + \bar{c}b = 0$$
use

\begin{align}
  s_0 &= \bar{b} \\
  c_0 &= \bar{a} \\
  \Rightarrow c &= \frac{c_0}{\sqrt{|c_0|^2 + |s_0|^2}} \\
  \Rightarrow s &= \frac{s_0}{\sqrt{|c_0|^2 + |s_0|^2}} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

I just saw your email. Of course we can do that.

Example (in MATLAB):

% ---------------------------------------------
    n=3; 
    a=2+3j;
    b=4-3j;

```
A=a*eye(n);
B=b*eye(n);

n2=2*n;
X=zeros(n2);
X(1:n,1:n)=A;
X(n+1:n2,n+1:n2)=B;    

[U,T]=Grigoryan_code(X);

U'*T % = X
```

% --------------------------- end of code
U =

0.5547 - 0.8321i        0                  0                  0                  0                  0
        0             0.5547 - 0.8321i        0                  0                  0                  0
        0                  0             0.5547 - 0.8321i        0                  0                  0
        0                  0                  0             0.8000 + 0.6000i        0                  0
        0                  0                  0                  0             0.8000 + 0.6000i        0
        0                  0                  0                  0                  0             1.0000

T =

3.6056                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
        0             3.6056                  0                  0                  0                  0
        0                  0             3.6056                  0                  0                  0
        0                  0                  0             5.0000                  0                  0
        0                  0                  0                  0             5.0000                  0
        0                  0                  0                  0                  0             4.0000 - 3.0000i

ans =

2.0000 + 3.0000i        0                  0                  0                  0                  0
        0             2.0000 + 3.0000i        0                  0                  0                  0
        0                  0             2.0000 + 3.0000i        0                  0                  0
        0                  0                  0             4.0000 - 3.0000i        0                  0
        0                  0                  0                  0             4.0000 - 3.0000i        0
        0                  0                  0                  0                  0             4.0000 - 3.0000i

You can check it. It works.

Art Grigoryan
UTSA

Comment: Hi Dr. Grigoryan, we have never met but I have heard good things. I voted you up here because I think you would be a good addition to the site, but I wanted to note that you may want to expand on your Grigoryan_code(X) here.